# How to add two series on the same chart area in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have made a chart like this from the Adventureworks database.

[image]

I had used the following table, querying from the Adventureworks database.

```
Employee  | OrderYear  | OrderMonth |ProdCat    |    Sales
=============================================================
Shu Ito   |  2002      |  April     |Accessories| 565.222000
Shu Ito   |  2002      |  April     |Clothing   | 917.077000
Shu Ito   |  2002      |  April     |Components | 6149.999400
Shu Ito   |  2003      |  April     |Accessories| 288.859000
Shu Ito   |  2003      |  April     |Clothing   | 1661.651092
Shu Ito   |  2003      |  April     |Components | 11497.001600
Shu Ito   |  2004      |  April     |Accessories| 4960.536837
Shu Ito   |  2004      |  April     |Clothing   | 7947.791216
Shu Ito   |  2004      |  April     |Components | 29866.476000
```

The chart properties were like this.
[image]

What I want is to add another column under each of the years (i.e. another series) that records the total sales of that year. (Total sales of Accessories, Clothing and Components)

I figured out that, I need to add a series using an expression, but I am not being able to write the expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a calculated column doing the sum of sales for the period and display it on a secondary axis.

There is also an option (though i can't tell you what it is as i haven't got ssrs in front of me) that allows you to add a 'Grouping' that will display the sum / count etc of the items in the x axis group.

I'll see if i can pin it down for you